# ¿Cómo resetear numero de ecuación en un \begin{align} en LaTeX?

Tags: latex

Tengo el siguiente código en Overleaf:

```
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\Lagr}{\partial x_{1}} &= x_{2} + 2x_{1}\lambda_{1} = 0 \\ \frac{\partial\Lagr}{\partial x_{2}} &= x_{1} + x_{3} + 2x_{2}\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2} = 0\\
%
\frac{\partial\Lagr}{\partial x_{3}} &= x_{2} + \lambda_{2} = 0\\
%
\frac{\partial\Lagr}{\partial \lambda_{1}} &= x_{1}^2 + x_{2}^2 - 2 = 0 \\ \frac{\partial\Lagr}{\partial \lambda_{2}} &= x_{2} + x_{3} -2 = 0 
\end{align}
```

El cual me genera esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual si es lo que quiero, sin embargo, más adelante hago otro `\begin{align}` en el que quiero que se reseteen los números de las ecuaciones, que comiencen de 1 de nuevo, esto tiene el siguiente codigo:

```
\begin{align}
-2\cdot\alpha_{1} &= 0\\
2\cdot\alpha_{1} + \alpha_{2} &= 0\\
\alpha_{2} &= 0\\
\Rightarrow \alpha_{1} = \alpha_{2} &= 0
\end{align}
```

Y este continúa con la secuencia de números:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cosa que no es lo que quiero.

Por ahí encontré comandos como:

1. \newcounter{foo}[counter]
2. \setcounter{counter}{0}

Y no me funcionan, o no se como utilizarlos en estas secciones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El comando para reiniciar un contador es `\setcounter{contador}{0}`. El truco está en conocer cómo se llama el contador que quieres reiniciar.

En el caso de las ecuaciones, el contador se llama `equation`, por tanto basta con poner la línea siguiente antes del segundo `align`:

```
\setcounter{equation}{0}
```

> [image: Resultado]

Comment: Como decía, no sabía utilizarlos. Jajaja, muchas gracias, estaré al tanto de darte la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Un enfoque distinto al problema, sería usar `{subequations}`

```
Primer grupo

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    -2\cdot\alpha_{1} &= 0\\
    2\cdot\alpha_{1} + \alpha_{2} &= 0\\
    \alpha_{2} &= 0\\
    \Rightarrow \alpha_{1} = \alpha_{2} &= 0
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

Segundo grupo

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    -2\cdot\alpha_{1} &= 0\\
    2\cdot\alpha_{1} + \alpha_{2} &= 0\\
    \alpha_{2} &= 0\\
    \Rightarrow \alpha_{1} = \alpha_{2} &= 0
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sino, y como complemento de la respuesta de abulafia, puedes usar `etoolbox` para  conectar el evento de inicio de los `align` y reiniciar el contador de estos de forma automática

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{\setcounter{equation}{0}}

\begin{document}

Grupo 1
\begin{align}
-2\cdot\alpha_{1} &= 0\\
2\cdot\alpha_{1} + \alpha_{2} &= 0\\
\alpha_{2} &= 0\\
\Rightarrow \alpha_{1} = \alpha_{2} &= 0
\end{align}

Aquí el otro grupo, con reseteo de numeración
\begin{align}
-2\cdot\alpha_{1} &= 0\\
2\cdot\alpha_{1} + \alpha_{2} &= 0\\
\alpha_{2} &= 0\\
\Rightarrow \alpha_{1} = \alpha_{2} &= 0
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muy buena información adicional, gracias. Se me paso por la cabeza que existiera algo así, y al parecer estaba en lo correcto.